# Como convertir un entry() en input()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hola estoy haciendo un programa en tkinter que trata de una lista a la que puedes añadir y remover lo que el usuario ingrese. Para que el usuario agregue algo necesito que cuando presione enter la información que halla en el `entry()"` se guarde y se ejecute un código. Como puedo hacerlo?

El Codigo:

```
import tkinter as tk



def agregar():
    bA.place_forget()
    bR.place_forget()

    label = tk.Label(ventana, text = "Que desea agregar?", width = 31, fg = "black")
    label.place(x = 40, y = 100)

    var_e = tk.StringVar()

    ent = tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable = var_e, width = 42, fg = "black")
    ent.place(x = 20, y = 130)

def remover():
    pass



ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.title("Lista")
ventana.geometry('300x250')

var_L = tk.StringVar()

Lista = tk.Label(ventana, textvariable = var_L, width = 31, bg = "white", bd = 20)
Lista.place(x = 20, y = 32)


bA = tk.Button(ventana, text = "Agregar", width = 15, fg = "black", command = agregar)
bA.place(x = 20, y = 120)

bR = tk.Button(ventana, text = "Remover", width = 15, fg = "black", command = remover)         
bR.place(x = 165, y = 120)

bS = tk.Button(ventana, text = "Salir", width = 7, fg = "black", command = quit)
bS.place(x = 120, y = 200)


ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

en primer lugar creas la rutina que reaccionará al `<Enter>` del usuario, por ejemplo esto imprimirá por consola el texto ingresado:

```
def ent_get(event):
   print(event.widget.get())
```

Luego simplemente hay que "escuchar" un nuevo evento cuando el usuario presiona `<Enter>` e invocar a nuestra rutina, esto lo haremos en `agregar()` luego de haber creado el `Entry` `ent`

```
ent.bind('<Return>', ent_get)
```